# How can I add a cardview to the Toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design

Based off the Phone app (on my Moto X, but I believe it may be the same as stock) - it seems that there is a search bar and then a swipeable CardView above the TabLayout. So either:

a) The `Toolbar` has been modified to include a CardView, or

b) the `TabLayout` has been shifted to some position other than the top of the screen.

Does anyone know how this effect can be achieved? I've played around with this but haven't found a way to achieve either.

Comment: Try UiAutomatorview to find out about the widget.

Comment: There's a Toolbar inside a CardView at the top, a CardView with custom Behavior (see support design library) and a TabLayout. You can put all this into an AppBarLayout and that plus content into a CoordinatorLayout.